# If G is a group of order $pq$, where $p$ and $q$ are primes. How do I prove that any nontrivial subgroup of $G$ must be cyclic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This makes sense since $p$ and $q$ are primes but I'm not sure how I can prove that the subgroup will be cyclic?

Will the generator of the subgroup be $pq$?

Comment: It's just Lagrange theorem that gives you that the order of a subgroup divides the order of a group and then that all subgroups of prime order are cyclic

Comment: Perhaps there is an issue here about the word "nontrivial". If it is intended to be a non-identity proper subgroup, then the statement is true. Sometimes people use the term non-trivial subgroup to mean a non-identity subgroup. In this case, it need not be the case that $G$ itself is cyclic- consider the group $S_{3},$ for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just an application of Lagrange theorem and the definition of primes.

I give a completely fleshed out answer in light of the comments. Note that all groups are assumed finite.

From Lagrange theorem we know that if $H\leq G$ (is a subgroup of) then $|H|$ divides the order of $G$.

Now if we suppose that $H\leq G$ and $H$ is non-trivial (not equal to $\{e\}$ or $G$) then we have that $|H| | |G|$ so that $|H| | pq$

But by the definition of prime this gives that either $|H| | p$ or $|H| | q$ and as $H$ was assumed to be non-trivial this then gives that either $|H|=p$ or $|H|=q$

We now need to show that if a group has order $p$ then it is cyclic and we are done.

So let $H$ be a group of prime order and pick $g\in H$ such that $g\neq e$ then again from Lagrange theorem we have that $o(g)|H|$ and so $o(g)|p$ but as $g$ was assume not to be the identity we have that $o(g)>1$ and so $o(g)=p$

This then gives that $\langle g \rangle $ (cyclic subgroup generated by $g$) has order $p$ and as $\langle g \rangle \leq H$ we have that they are equal and so $H$ is cyclic.

Answer (score 1):

A non trivial subgroup of $G$ has order $p$ or $q$, hence it's cyclic beacuse $p$ and $q$ are prime numbers.

Comment: Would this be all I need? The answer/proof seems a bit trivial (pun intended). But it makes sense! Thank you

Comment: Yes, I use the fact that the order of a subgroup divide the order of the group and that group with prime order are cyclic.

Comment: @Roy: Consider any nonidentity element $a$ of a subgroup of order $p$, what is the order of the group that it generates ($\{a^k\mid k\in\Bbb Z\}$)?