# let G be a group of order pq,where p and q are primes. Show that any non-trivial subgroup of G is cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra

let G be a group of order pq,where p and q are primes. Show that any non-trivial subgroup of G is cyclic

how do we exactly go about doing this question

Comment: How large is a non-trivial subgroup?

Comment: Use Lagrange Theorem **twice**

Comment: I think you mean any *proper* subgroup is cyclic.

Comment: I Googled the title: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/700967/if-g-is-a-group-of-order-pq-where-p-and-q-are-primes-how-do-i-prove-that

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that nontrivial also means it is proper. Let $H$ be such a subgroup of $G$, and suppose that $H$ is not cyclic. Let $h$ a non-identity element of $H$, and consider the cyclic subgroup $\langle h \rangle$ generated by $\langle h \rangle$.

Since $\langle h \rangle\subset H \subset G$, we cannot have that $\langle h \rangle = G$, since that would imply that $H$ is not proper. Therefore $\langle h \rangle$ is proper in $G$.

By Lagrange's Theorem, $|\langle h \rangle|$ must divide $|G|=pq$, and from before $|\langle h \rangle|\neq pq$. So, either $|\langle h \rangle|=p$ or $|\langle h \rangle|=q$. Without loss of generality, suppose $\langle h \rangle$ has order $p$.

Since $H$ is not cyclic, we have that $\langle h \rangle\subsetneq H \subsetneq G$. However the order $O_H=|H|$ of $H$ must satisfy

$$ |\langle h \rangle|=p\mid O_H\mid pq=|G| $$

which implies that $O_H=pq$ or $O_H=p$. This means that either $H=\langle h \rangle$ or $H=G$, a contradiction.

Therefore $H$ is cyclic.